# ORDER BY multiple data(many-to-many) doesn't work

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I have tables which has manytomany value.

One TagData row has multiple VideoData ids.

```
class TagData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=false,nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VideoData", mappedBy="tagIds", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $videoIds;

    /**
    * Get videos
    *
    * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
    */
    public function getVideos()
    {
        return $this->videos;
    }
```

and VideoData table

```
class VideoData implements ItemInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\TagData",inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tag_video")
     * )
     */
    private $tagIds;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;
```

What I want to do is:

Getting VideoIds which belongs to one TagData row, with this conditions

1) sorted by 'updatedAt'

For now, mysql is like this below .

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT t FROM TagData t JOIN t.videoIds v WHERE
        t.id = {$id} order by v.updatedAt");
```

then pick up the videoIds by

```
$videos = $query->getVideoIds(); // but this data is not sorted by updatedAt
```

Why this ORDER BY does not working?

How can I make it?

Comment: hey is tagdata a table here ?

Comment: what is acmetop bundle ?..is it also a table so you have both tables here ?

Comment: ah tagdata is table. I have two tables TagData and VideoData.I re-write the article